# Installing .msi on Windows 10 - Windows Installer flashes on screen then does nothing

Tags: windows-10, windows-installer

Every time I try to install an .msi file the Windows Installer flashes on screen for a moment, "Preparing to install...", then nothing happens. I've tried a few different .msi files and gotten the same result with all of them.
I should probably add that .exe installers work as expected.

[image: Preparing to install...]

*The gif shows me running the .msi from cmd, I usually run them from Explorer, this is just what I happened to be doing when I decided to record the screen to be able to read what the pop-up said.*

Each time I try to install an .msi file a new entry of Windows Installer is added to the task manager. If I don't end the Windows Installer task, after about 15-20 minutes I get a pop up saying <strike>that the install failed, I don't remember the exact message, I'll try to catch it next time I see it.</strike> "Installer is no longer responding".

[image: Installer is no longer responding]

Things I've tried so far:

- Restarting the Windows Installer service (from system32\services.msc)
- Executing the following commands in cmd:

  1. Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
  2. Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
  3. Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
- Running CCleaner's registry cleaning tool
- [Modifying the Windows registry to be able to run the .msi files as Administrator](https://www.howtogeek.com/178826/how-to-force-an-msi-package-to-install-using-administrator-mode/)
- Restarting the MSIServer as you can see in the above gif

Comment: Try right-clicking on the file and there should be __Install__ on the top of the list. If it does not install it should be able to tell you why it cannot, like it is not a 32-bit software, etc. Are on a x64 Windows ?

Comment: @vssher Hi, yes, that's what I'm doing to install it, the gif shows me doing the equivalent from the cmd window. What you see in the gif and what I've explained is all that happens, sadly no errors.

Comment: Does it happen with any .msi file?  Instead of replying with a temporary comment you should edit your question.

Comment: @Ramhound Hi, yes, maybe the question was unclear on the matter, I'll edit it like you suggested.

Comment: Have you tried opening it with Explorer.exe? Then right-click on it and choose Install. I have never opened or installed any .msi using a command prompt or PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the problem was linked to a node.js installation, which is when it first started acting up.

I fixed the issue with the following steps:

- downloaded the exact version of node.js I had installed previously
- restarted Windows with a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows) (without this step the next one didn't work for me)
- right-click on the node.js installer and Install
- right-click on the node.js installer and Uninstall
- reset Windows boot options to boot normally
- restarted Windows

.msi installers now seem to be working as expected

Answer (score 1):

You may have scripting turned off.

Check these two keys

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings

   *and*
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings

Look for **Enabled**  with a **REG_DWORD**


1 = Enabled and 0 = Disabled.

There are also other data keys in Policies which may have wscript.exe and script.exe with **DisallowRun**


HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer

   *and*
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer

Comment: Hi, I've added the Enabled DWORD at the location you suggested, see the last edit of the question.
I checked for the DisallowRun but didn't find it.
Thanks for your advice but the problem still persists :(

Comment: @Daniel the better way to enable it is to remove the _Enabled_ all together, I was just suggesting you see if it exists. I would try running any and all .msi scripts from Explorer, or from the Desktop.

Comment: Ok, I will revert the last edit and remove the Enabled key from the registry. As I said in my previous comment I do usually run them from explorer, the gif just shows me running from cmd as that's what I happened to record when I wanted to be able to see what the pop-up said.
Thanks again.

Comment: @Daniel It looks like it says Node.JS (Java Script). I have extracted .msi files using 7-Zip and have run the files from the created folder. You might want to try that, however sometimes it comes come out as RAW data files.

Comment: I tried extracting the contents of the .msi as you suggested, the only "runnable" file I see is "node.exe" which actually opens a working node session in the terminal, it's pretty cool that it works but I couldn't find anything to actually install node.
I should reiterate that the problem is not with a specific .msi but with all the ones I've tried, like for example the .msi to install sbt (scala build tool).

Comment: @Daniel Installing SBT on Windows https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Windows.html

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I think you are missing the point. 
If I go to that page and click "Download msi installer and install it.", the same exact problem presents iself (windows installer pop-up flashes, then nothing). Of course I can install sbt in another way, but that's not my problem, i already have sbt installed and was just testing the .msi file, my problem is that I cannot install anything using .msi files in Windows.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on how the Windows Scripting Host related to an MSI package? Because I don’t see it.